# Segue to DetailViewController (SplitViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I'm having a hard time selecting the view controller that show be the detail view in the split view controller.  It appears that there is some default caller to the view controller behind `showDetail` but I cannot find where.  When the split view controller loads, it show `DetailViewController` as the detail in split of my attempts to set it to `OverviewViewController`. The `showDetail` segue is not called on load, however it is still the default.

When I have overrided the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on the master, I see a flicker as it sets the `DetailViewController` briefly before setting `OverviewViewController`.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? OverviewViewController

    }
}

// MARK: - Segues
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("did select row")
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showOverview", sender: self)
    }

}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        print("segue to showDetail")
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.injectOrder(gobl_meal_orders[indexPath.row])
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }else if segue.identifier == "showOverview"{
        print("show overview called")
    }
}
```

Where is this hidden preselection of view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,  you don't want the detail view to be displayed when your splitview controller is loaded.

The way to control this is to use a custom class for your UISplitViewController and implement the following delegate method

[splitViewController(_:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:)

Here is an example.

```
import UIKit

class MyCircleUISplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true
  }      
}
```

Here is also a nice [blog](http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/) on UISplitViewControllers that you might find interesting.